# Three concerns on this passage. Could you just simplify the highlighted parts?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> This movement is especially in evidence in those clusters where a local Mashriqu’l-Adhkár is to be established. One such, by way of example, is in Vanuatu. The friends who reside on the island of Tanna have made a supreme effort to raise consciousness of the planned House of Worship, and have already engaged no less than a third of the island’s 30,000 inhabitants **in an expanding conversation about its significance in a variety of ways** . The ability **to sustain an elevated conversation** among so many people has been **refined** through years of experience sharing the teachings of Bahá’u’lláh and extending **the reach of a vibrant training institute** . Junior youth groups on the island are particularly thriving, urged on by the support of village chiefs who see how the participants are spiritually empowered. Encouraged by the unity and dedication that exist among them, these young people have not only dispelled the languor of passivity in themselves but have, through various practical projects, found means to work for the betterment of their community, and as a result, those of all ages, not least their own parents, have been galvanized into constructive action. Among the believers and the wider society, the bounty of being able to turn to a Local Spiritual Assembly for guidance and for the resolution of difficult situations is being recognized, and in turn, the decisions of the Spiritual Assemblies are increasingly characterized by wisdom and sensitivity. There is much here to indicate that, when the elements of the Plan’s framework for action are combined into a coherent whole, the impact on a population can be profound. And it is against the background of ongoing expansion and consolidation—the thirtieth cycle of the intensive programme of growth has recently concluded—that the friends are actively exploring, with the rest of the island’s inhabitants, what it means for a Mashriqu’l-Adhkár, a “collective centre for men’s souls”, to be raised up in their midst.

1. Could you simplify this part saying **in an expanding conversation about its significance in a variety of ways**, please?
2. What do the words **elevated** and **sustain** really mean in this phrase:  ** to sustain an elevated conversation** ?
3. What does it mean **the reach of** in this phrase ? **the reach of a vibrant training institute** . Could you simplify it please?

Answer (score 1):

> ... in an expanding conversation about its significance in a variety of ways .

Mainly, to find the meaning of these we first need to clarify what pronouns refer to.

- What have one-third of the inhabitants done? They have engaged in a conversation.
- Who made them? Our fellows who reside in the island of Tanna.
- What's the conversation about? "Its importance". A little thought leads to finding what "it" is.

The House of Worship was planned, so "our fellows" must be people that **made a conversation about how important the House of Worship is.** The conversation was simply about worshipping and it was **expanding**, because at least 10000 people were involved in the conversation. Clear enough? :D

> The ability to sustain an elevated conversation among so many people has been refined through years of experience sharing the teachings of Bahá’u’lláh and extending the reach of a vibrant training institute.

The author of the article was praising those guys (the guys that made the conversation). To make and nourish such a conversation requires great ability, doesn't it? **They have improved this ability in themselves. The improvement was with teaching other people about the religion of that guy and with increasing the range of influence their institute has. This institute is very active.**

If it's still vague, comment me. Hope I've helped.